# Reduce an object containing arrays as values to single array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Question: Reduce an object containing arrays as values to single array based on a condition.
Details: I have an object containing arrays as values.

```
{
  514:["564"],
  812:["514"],
  1006:["921","812"],
  1012: ["1002"],
  1024:["6994","7992"],
  6923:["1024","1006"],
  6994:["1012","7182"],
  7992:["5921"],
}
```

I want to write a javascript function that can reduce this object to array based on key I am passing to function. The result array should have the id that we passed to function and it's value in object and also any other values corresponding to the values till the time we can find no keys.
For example: If I pass 6994, then I need result from function as following array

```
["6994", "1012", "7182", "1002"]
```

I tried and got the following to work. Wanted to know if there is a better more efficient solution:

```
function getChildIds({ treeMap, id }) {
  let childIds = [id];
  let parentIds = [id];
  while(!!parentIds.length) {
    let tempIds = [];
    parentIds.forEach((parentId, index) => {
      if(!!treeMap[parentId]) {
        tempIds.push(...treeMap[parentId]);
        childIds.push(...treeMap[parentId]);
      }
    });
    parentIds = tempIds;
  }
  return childIds;
}
```

Edit: Recursion is not preferred since this object can be quite huge and running out of browser stack memory is not desirable.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand how "1002" related there? D

Comment: @HalilÇakar It's the value which can be found in the key `1012`, which is one of the values that were found when looking at `6994`. Basically, every time you have a value, you check whether it's also a key, then take the corresponding values, and repeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the nested nodes from the given node.

Type: Depth-first search: In-order (LNR)

```js
const
    getNodes = node => [node, ...(nodes[node] || []).flatMap(getNodes)],
    nodes = { 514: ["564"], 812: ["514"], 1006: ["921", "812"], 1012: ["1002"],  1024: ["6994", "7992"], 6923: ["1024", "1006"], 6994: ["1012", "7182"], 7992: ["5921"] },
    node = "6994",
    result = getNodes(node);

console.log(result);
```

Another approach uses a stack, which might be faster than the above recursive `reduce` approach.

The order of this approach is different, because the [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) is in level order ([breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)).

```js
const
    getNodes = node => {
        const
            stack = [node],
            result = [];

        while (stack.length) {
            const
                n = stack.shift();
            result.push(n);
            if (!nodes[n]) continue;
            stack.push(...nodes[n]);                   
        }
        return result; 
    },
    nodes = { 514: ["564"], 812: ["514"], 1006: ["921", "812"], 1012: ["1002"],  1024: ["6994", "7992"], 6923: ["1024", "1006"], 6994: ["1012", "7182"], 7992: ["5921"] },
    node = "6994",
    result = getNodes(node);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Recursion is not preferred since this object can be quite huge and running out of browser stack memory is not preferable.

Comment: I will accept your answer since it is very concise and use of es6 function. If you can, please share some performance insights to this function. I am somewhat worried about use of recursion.

Comment: Your second answer using fifo queue object is much better IMO. It has no recursion and number of iterations equals the number elements in result. O(n)